# Amazon Interview about Success probability

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failure rate of a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819334/failure-rate-of-a-system)

If a system has a 10% independent chance of failing in any given hour, what are the chances of it failing in a given 2 hour period or n-hours period?
Note: 10% failure probability in 1 hour has nothing to do with 10% of the time . It's just that a system has a 10% independent chance of failing in any given hour

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6819375/1791606

Comment: @Qoop- Ya, I checked that but in that question, failing probability is 10% of the time but in this question, failing probability of 10% is not 10% of the time, it's just related to the system. I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks for your help. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

- Let `P`<sub>`fail`</sub> be the probability that the system fails in any given hour.
- Then `P`<sub>`nofail`</sub>, the probability that the system does not fail in any given hour, is `1 - P`<sub>`fail`</sub>.
- The chance of it not failing in 2 hours is (`P`<sub>`nofail`</sub>)<sup>`2`</sup>, since it must independently not-fail in each of those hours, and [the joint probability of two independent events is the product of the probability of each event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events) (that is, *`P(A ∩ B) = P(A)*P(B)`*).
- More generally, then, the `chance of it not failing in n hours` is (`P`<sub>`nofail`</sub>)<sup>`n`</sup>  .
- The chance of it failing in `n` hours is `1 - (chance of not failing in n hours)`.

You should be able to work it out from there.